# Data Conversion matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array, data-conversion

I am trying to convert the entire cell array below to cell array of strings and I am using:

```
C = cellfun(@num2str, final, 'UniformOutput', false);

final = 

    {'3F'   21  'F' '3/26/2014' 'P0702' []  []  []  []  []  []  []  
    '3F'    201 'F' '11/4/2014' 'P0702' 'P0882' []  []  []  []  []  
    '3F'    010 'F' '10/19/2014''P0715' 'P0717' []  []  []  []  []  
    '3L'    014 'M' '12/8/2014' 'P0710' 'P0743' 'P0753' []  []  [] }
```

It gives me an error

> ??? Undefined function or method 'fix' for input arguments of type
>   'cell'.
>
> > Error in ==> num2str at 66
> >             if ~isempty(x) && isequalwithequalnans(x, fix(x))

I have tried the required data type conversion but i am missing it somewhere.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: There is problem in your cell array assignment code you provided. Is this how you actually created the cell array `final`? If I correct the syntax error, the conversion works well.

Comment: I might have made a mistake in copying it here , are you talking about the syntax Error in the date column last row,if that's the case that's a copy paste error

Comment: the assignment should be `final = {'3F'  21  'F'.....}` but not `{final} = `'3F'  21  'F'.....`

Comment: Yes , that is how it is! My apologies ,It still gives me the same error ,can I know the class for any row from column 5 .it works fine if I use it from colums 1 to 4 ,it doesn't work from column 5 onwards

Comment: If that's the case, please post what's in column 5.

Comment: Column 5 to 10 is already shown above .this is exactly how it is

Comment: To know the class of cell array content : `class(final{i,j})`

Answer (score 0):

The codes regarding the cell array is not in valid MATLAB syntax. It should be formatted like this:

```
final = {'3F' 21  'F' '3/26/2014' 'P0702' []  []  []  []  []  [];  
         '3F' 201 'F' '11/4/2014' 'P0702' 'P0882' []  []  []  []  [];
         '3F' 010 'F' '10/19/2014' 'P0715' 'P0717' []  []  []  [] [];
         '3L' 014 'M' '12/8/2014' 'P0710' 'P0743' 'P0753' []  []  [] []}
```

Comment: when i check for class(final{1,5}) it would give me class= cell .

Comment: Will you get that if you use the cell array I posted above?  I think on your end, you do have a cell array within a cell array. If that's the case, you need to take one step back and examine the data import/generation process.

Comment: yeah but i figured it out.You were right.Had to do a lot of data type conversions to  get it.Thanks for the inputs and your time.Appreciate it.